# How to create a custom tkinter Combobox with no arrow if there are 0 or 1 items?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am writing a program which merges data from several sources into a spreadsheet. If the data for a cell is different from different sources, a human needs to choose the best one, so I want it to be obvious which cells need to be reviewed.

Not displaying the arrow when the data for the `Combobox.set()` has 0 or one item seems a good way, but I don't understand `ttk` styles and layouts well enough to do it.

Comment: You have either misread or ignored my comment. The part of styles and layouts I don't understand in this case is how the underlying code interacts with data in styles and layouts to control display of elements of a widget. It may be impossible to do what I want with a combobox, but I surely won't learn that in a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get the effect I want. I create both a Label and a Combobox at the same location and use .lift() to put the one I want on top.